# KeyBoard Issue when using TabHost in android

Tags: android, keyboard

Hi I am using four tabs in my tabhost, named TabOne, TabTwo, TabThree, TabFour.

In TabOne I have editext to make search option, when I pressed in edit text it show the keyboard. 
But without closing the keyboard When I move to TabTwo the keyboard still showing. I dont want the keyboard should enable in TabTwo,TabThree,TabFour. 
Because all other three tabs are not having edittext option.

Now My question is how to hide keyboard when clicked on the other tabs.

I have tried the below methods,

Adding the below code in `oncreate` method of TabB

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Adding the below xml tag in Android manifest file

```
     android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

Please guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: did u find the solution of this problem ...i also have same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide edit text when it lose focus.

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if (!hasFocus) {
        hideKeyboard();
    }
   }
```

});

```
void hideKeyboard() {
   InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)  getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
}
```

Comment: hi but your code again made a problem for the first time when i come to second tab the keyboard will hide. But when I did this again and again in the other tab it automatically raises the keyboard.Please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this answer

enable the soft keyboard

```
inputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

and disable the soft keyboard

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: Hi I have tried this but this will not suits for my situation.That is when enabling the keyboard and moving to next tab but still showing the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me:**

In the Activity which is triggered when you click on the specific Tab, I used this in onCreate:

```
inputSearch.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(inputSearch.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
           }});
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml, I added the following to my MainActivity (Where all Tabs are defined):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

This single line will work for you. check this out.